# ArcGIS Print Javascript API return syntax error after installing SSL certificate

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, printing, ssl

I've been facing problems with my printing service using ArcGIS JavaScript API 3.22 and ArcGIS server 10.1 after installing SSL certificate on the ArcGIS server. 
The printing service return the SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in the init.js and Print.js file. I've done some digging and found that this problem will occur while printing large amount of graphics on the FeatureLayer. Is there any configuration I need to do on the ArcGIS server after installing SSL certificate so that it can print large amount of graphics because i did not face this problem while printing on ArcGIS server without SSL certificate.

Comment: You might want to check the network tab in your browser's devtools and inspect that print request/response - to me it sounds like your ArcGIS Server responded with some kind of HTML page, possibly an error message

Comment: Ya i've found that the ArcGIS server responded some HTML page (see the image above) instead of the json message. If success printing I get this message:

Answer (score 1):

Is this is a windows server? If yes, have you installed the certificate in both root and intermediate?
start->run->mmc->file->add/remove snap-in->certificates->add->computer account ->local computer -> ok -> expand certificates -> expand trusted root -> click certificates -> is the cert there? if not import it -> right click certificate -> All tasks import browse out to where the certificate is located. -> click Intermediate Certificate -> certificates -> is the cert there? if not import it -> right click certificate -> All tasks import browse out to where the certificate is located.

Close the Console. Don't Save.

some other things to test, outside of javascript can you browse to the print url on the local host without getting a cert error? If no, then install the certificate at that level on the server.

Otherwise in JavaScript there might be new code that you'll need to implement to work with SSL.